# Unable to use function with colors

Tags: apexcharts

I created a mixed chart of line and scatter, I want to hide the scatters that have a value equal to 0, hence if the value is 0 the maker will be visible (#FFFFFF)

My current code as below

```js
const Chart1 = () => {
  const series = [{
    name: 'Points',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [236, 120, 127, 176, 190, 158, 133, 201, 227, 152, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  }, {
    name: 'Points',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [120, 100, 150, 130, 200, 342, 213, 312, 334, 321, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  }, {
    name: 'Line',
    type: 'line',
    data: [140, 150, 230, 180, 342, 256, 157, 452, 113, 389, 123, 456, 231, 654, 234],
  }];

  const options = {
    chart: {
      height: 350,
      type: 'line',
    },
    stroke: {
      curve: 'smooth',
      colors: ['#4d3347'],
      width: 2.5,
    },
    fill: {
      type: 'solid',
    },
    markers: {
      size: 4,
      colors: [function({ value }) {
        if (value < 0) {
          return '#FFFFFF'; // Set marker color to #FFFFFF if value is less than 0
        } else {
          return '#FB6D10'; // Default color
        }
      }],
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: false,
      intersect: true,
    },
    legend: {
      show: false
    },

    theme: {
      monochrome: {
        enabled: true, 
        shadeIntensity: 0
      }
    }, 
    dataLabels: { enabled: true, enabledOnSeries: [] },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'category',
      categories: ['Phường 11', 'Phường 1', 'Phường 10', 'Phường 12', 'Phường 13', 'Phường 14', 'Phường 15', 'Phường 2', 'Phường 3', 'Phường 4', 'Phường 5', 'Phường 6', 'Phường 7', 'Phường 8', 'Phường 9'],
    },
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex justify-center w-full bg-white font-inter'>
      <div className='flex flex-row gap-8 w-3/4 justify-center'>
        <div className='flex flex-col w-8/12 max-w-[52rem] divide-y gap-8'>
          <div className='flex flex-col gap-6 pt-8'>
            <h2 className='text-xl font-medium'>BDS Hiển Thị Giá Theo Khu Vực</h2>
            <div id="chart">
              <ReactApexChart options={options} series={series} type="line" height={350} />
            </div>
            <div id="html-dist"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='w-4/12 max-w-[20rem]'>
          <NavBar />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The property `options.marker.colors` can only be used to set one color per
dataset. Fortunately, there's [`options.marker.discrete`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/markers#markerDiscrete)
that allows you to set properties for individual markers.

You can then iterate through all the series, and through all the values
in each series, pick those with `value === 0` and add an entry in the `discrete`
array with the series index, data point index and the desired colors; `size`
appears to be a compulsory entry - setting is to zero makes the marker invisible,
if that was the objective:

```js
    markers: {
        size: 4,
        colors: [
            '#f00', '#00f' // set default colors for the two series
        ],
        discrete: series.flatMap( // for each data in series
            ({data}, seriesIndex) => data.map( // for each value in data
                (value, dataPointIndex) => value === 0 ? ({ // if value is zero
                    seriesIndex,
                    dataPointIndex,
                    fillColor: '#fff',  
                    strokeColor: '#fff',
                    size: 0,
                }): 
                    null // otherwise null
            )
        ).filter(x=>x) // finally filter out null's
    },
```